# Pages of website returns a WAMP homepage on my LocalHost?

Tags: localhost, wamp, wordpress, virtual-host

Using WAMPSERVER for windows 7, smartgit and Safe Search Replace I have done the following steps:

- Pulled a wordpress code from a github repository using smartgit
- Downloaded the database from the server's phpmyadmin
- Imported it to my localhost's phpmyadmin using WAMP.
- Replaced the strings from url.com to `127.0.0.1/url`

The home page of the website works on the localhost but when I click on one of the menu links I get the WAMP homepage instead of the actual page.

On the wordpress dashboard, I have checked and the URL on pages has been changed to `127.0.0.1/url` which is a good sign.I have also checked in the database the actual name of the the page and even the `127.0.0.1/id` page did showed a WAMP home page.

I have tried renaming index.php to index.php.old and replacing it with the index.php from the root folder of a fresh download of WordPress but it did not help.

I have tried the following in WP-Config to use the localhost URL instead of the one saved to the database but it didn't work:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://127.0.0.1/website'); 
define('WP_SITEURL','http://127.0.0.1/website');
```

What have I done wrong and what can I check to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings/permalinks in the wordpress dashboard and update permalinks by clicking twice on save changes. That's all.